# Use a for loop to create a new dictionary using keys from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program for a python class.  I have been given a dictionary to start with like so:

```
aa2mw = {
    'A': 89.093,  'G': 75.067,  'M': 149.211, 'S': 105.093, 'C': 121.158,
    'H': 155.155, 'N': 132.118, 'T': 119.119, 'D': 133.103, 'I': 131.173,
    'P': 115.131, 'V': 117.146, 'E': 147.129, 'K': 146.188, 'Q': 146.145,
    'W': 204.225,  'F': 165.189, 'L': 131.173, 'R': 174.201, 'Y': 181.189
    }
```

I want to create a new dictionary using all of the keys from aa2mw, but with new values.  The values would be calculated using a string of arbitrary length like this: `(inString.count(A) / len(inString))` where A would be a single letter that matches the keys. Rather than type in each key one by one, is it possible to use a loop to make all the keys in the new dictionary the same as aa2mw?  I tried to write this, but kept running into syntax errors because I wasn't sure how to combine a loop with a dictionary.  My best, yet messy attempt looks like this:

```
aaCompositionDict = {key for key in aa2mw.items(): (self.inString.count(key) / len(self.inString))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, but the syntax is a bit off. Try this:

```
aaCompositionDict = {key: (self.inString.count(key) / len(self.inString)) for key, _ in aa2mw.items()}
```

Comment: This worked!  I'm very grateful, but I'm still not sure how the line works entirely.  How does the 'for key, _ in aa2mw.items()' section work?

Comment: @LucasKing `.items()` will give a bunch of tuples to iterate through in the form `(key, value)`. We only need the first one, so we unpack through `key, _` (`_` is convention for something we don't need). Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! For future viewers, you should accept the answer that answers your question best. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers